# Assigning Variable with Value of Existing Variable from String Value

Tags: python, string, variables, variable-assignment

I have a large amount of data in variable form:

```
abc_123 = 5  
def_456 = 7  
ghi_789 = 9
```

etc.

I ask the user for various inputs, which builds up a string. For example:

```
temp = "abc_123"
```

How do I make it so that temp = abc_123, thus making temp = 5?

Comment: Don't use variable variables, use a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a *dictionary* and then look up the values by key:

```
>>> d = {"abc_123": 5, "def_456": 7, "ghi_789": 9}
>>> temp = "abc_123"
>>> d[temp]
5
>>> d.get("invalid", "not found")
'not found'
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked great. It took some time to rearrange all the data in that format, but it wasn't excruciating enough to write code just to do that.